# How to update all rows of a table with an aggregate value referenced by foreign key on an another table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entityframework.extended

I have a users table and my `User` entity has a `Rating` column. A `User` has a navigation property called `IncomingRatings`, which is a one-to-many relationship of list of `Rate`s from a table called rates. A rating can be positive or negative, and is represented by the `IsPositive` boolean.

I want to find all the ratings of that user, and store it in the `Rating` column of my `User` table. Consider the following sample data:

```
RaterID | RatedID | IsPositive
1         2         1
4         1         0
5         2         1
2         3         0
3         2         1
7         2         0
6         1         1
```

In this case, for example, I want my user #2's (referenced by ID 2) `Rating` field to become 3, as there are 3 positive ratings for her.

After the updates, the users table should be like this:

```
UserID | Rating
1        1
2        3
3        0
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
```

Because I need this statement to run for 10000+ records, I can't use regular for loop in my ASP.NET website to update the records as it will save them one-by-one when I call `SaveChanges`. I've found [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended%20EntityFramework.Extended) which can update many records in a single call. Here is my two approaches:

```
db.Users.Where(u => true).Update(u => new User { Rating = u.IncomingRatings.Count(r => r.IsPositive) });
db.Users.Where(u => true).Update(u => new User { Rating = db.Rates.Where(r => r.RatedID == u.ID && r.IsPositive).Count() });
```

However, I am getting `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.` error in both queries. How can I update all rows with an aggregate value in Entity Framework 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `EntityFramework.Extended` is only capable of building simple UPDATE statement like

```sql
UPDATE User SET Rating = 3 WHERE ...
```

and not (or not yet)

```sql
UPDATE User SET Rating = (SELECT Count(*) FROM ... )
```

Too bad...

If doing the updates by regular EF updates, but with one `SaveChanges()` call, is too slow you could consider executing raw SQL to do the job.